# PHP-PDO: Display all rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm doing var_dump since I started to learn PHP/PDO when I want to display the SQL datas, like:

```
$tickets = $db->query('SELECT * FROM tickets')->fetchAll();
var_dump($tickets);
```

And it shows everything.

But now I'd like to `echo` a list of all **tickets name**, usually I would do an `echo $tickets->name;` but first it doesn't work with fetchAll(); and when I use fetch(); it returns only the last row

Noob question but all the answers I get are outdated and uses depreciated mysql, how can I just display the rows with PDO ?

Thanks !

Comment: what happens if you `var_dump($tickets);` you should an array of array or objects, then you can echo whatever you like

Comment: What one would normally do is call `fetch()` repeatedly, handling each record in turn, rather than loading the entire resultset into a PHP array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO `fetch_all` default to fetching both numeric and associative arrays

```
$tickets = $db->query('SELECT * FROM tickets')->fetchAll();
foreach($tickets as $ticket) {
    echo $ticket['name'];
}
```